# AlarmManager cancel multiple events

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

i'm developing an application where i need to set multiple alarm in a day.

Every time my application receives `Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGE` or `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` i schedule schedule the alarms for the current day.

Users from the application preferences can change if they want to receive alarm based reminders for each event category.

How can i cancel all the alarm just for a single category?

Actually I schedule events in this way:

```
AlarmManager alarmMan = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
for (MyCustomEvent evt : events) {
    Intent intentEvt = new Intent(context, ReceiverNotificationPublisher.class);
    // the id is long value
    intentEvt.putExtra(ReceiverNotificationPublisher.ITEM_ID, evt.getId());
    // the category is int value
    intentEvt.putExtra(ReceiverNotificationPublisher.ITEM_CATEGORY, evt.getCategory());

    // others values here

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, evt.getCategory(), intentEvt, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // set event
    alarmMan.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, evt.getTimestampMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Thanks to everyone in advance